# How to do train test split such that there are enough training and testing data from each class in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataset which is having 5 class and has a distribution as follows:

[image]

As is evident from the distribution that there are very less samples for class `1`.

How do I do a train-test split of this data so that there are enough training and testing data from each category in Python?

Comment: You may get 70% of each category..  something like `df.groupby('category').apply(train_test_split, args=0.7, ....)` where you fill in the right arguments instead of `args` etc

Comment: Normally, when you do `df.sample`, it would randomly sample your training set. Which, theoretically, would give you the same distribution of your classes. That said, you can always go extra mile and do what @rafaelc suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `stratify` parameter in `train_test_split` to be your target column.

`stratify` will ensure that each class gets split equally. [Doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#stratified-k-fold)

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y)`

Answer (score -1):

`train_test_split` function shuffles the dataset before splitting by default unless you provide `shuffle` parameters value as False. And I think it ensures that you training portion of dataset will have values from all the categories if `shuffle` is True. Additionally if you want train_test_split's outcome deterministic then you can use `random_state` parameter. Please see the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) to know more. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think your offered answer doesn't fulfill OP's request due to `train_test_split(...., test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)` does not ensure that samples going to be taken equally from each class. You might find the way to split your data manually by slicing data properly then feed to your NN or use ML on that.

Comment: As size of training samples from each categories may vary it may not possible every scenario to split training dataset equally from each category. I mentioned that it will ensure that from each categories at least some of samples will be taken in which i didn't mean equality. Thanks.

Comment: @RubelHassan since you accept that **As size of training samples from each categories may vary it may not possible every scenario to split training dataset equally from each category** then how does it answer the OP's question? Mind it, this question is related to a concept called **imbalanced data**. Therefore, its suggested that either you revise the proposed answer or delete it, lest it gets downvoted.

Comment: @mnm OP's question **How do I do a train-test split of this data so that there are __enough__ training and testing data from each category in Python?**, would you see where did he ask for equality.